# How declare in a record a member with generic list of records in F#

Tags: generics, f#, record

I'm stuck in how pass a generic list of records around. I wanna do this:

```
type TabularData<'T>= array<'T>
type Table = {title:string; data:TabularData<'T>} //This of course not work

type Cpu = 
  { name:string; load:int; }

type Memory = 
  { name:string; load:int; }

//F# not let me pass CPU or Memory
```

I wanna create any list of records of any type, and pass it around to serialize to json

P.D: More info about the issue.

I have forgott to add the main problem. Using generics it spread vast to the rest of the functions. So I need to tag EVERYTHING with a generic signature, so is possible to be more general and say: "I can have any kind of records here?"

Comment: type Table<'T> = {title:string; data:TabularData<'T>} ?

Answer (score 8):

You need to make the `Table` type generic too:

```
type Table<'T> = {title:string; data:TabularData<'T>}
```

And because your two records have the same fields, you can use `Cpu.name` to explicitly say that you are creating a table with CPU values:

```
{ title = "hi"; data = [| { Cpu.name = "test"; load = 1 } |]}
```